# JPA: "Can't write; duplicate key in table" for a One-to-One relationship

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have these entities that I want to relate bi-directionaly.

Credential:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "credential")
public class Credential extends MetaInfo implements Serializable {



    ...
    private Email email;

    ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="email", referencedColumnName="email_address")
    public Email getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(Email email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    ...
}
```

Email:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "email")
public class Email extends MetaInfo implements Serializable{

    ...
    private Credential credential;

    public Email() {
    }

    public Email(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }    

    @Id
    @Column(name="email_address")
    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "email", optional=false)
    public Credential getCredential() {
        return credential;
    }

    public void setCredential(Credential credential) {
        this.credential = credential;
    }
}
```

In a `CredentialRepository` class I am testing whether the passed-in email
is not assigned to any user except for the user with the username passed-in as the second (optional) parameter:

```
@Override
public boolean emailIsAssigned(String... args) {
    assert(args.length > 0);
    if(InputValidators.isValidEmail.test(args[0])){
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        try {
            TypedQuery<Long> count = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(e) "
                    + "FROM Email e WHERE e.emailAddress "
                    + "= :email AND e "
                    + "IN (SELECT c.email FROM Credential c WHERE c.username "
                    + "!= :username)", Long.TYPE).setParameter("email", args[0])
                    .setParameter("username", null);
            if(InputValidators.stringNotNullNorEmpty.apply(args[1])){
            //only if the username has been provided
                count.setParameter("username", args[1]);
            }
            return count.getSingleResult() > 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }else{
        throw new NotAValidEmailException(args[0] + " is not a"
                + " valid email address.");
    }
}
```

Thus above `args[0]` is the email under test and `args[1]` is the username under test.

And this is the test that is causing me problems (note that before I already successfully tested inserts, updates and even the `emailIsAssigned` method but without the `c.email` part which seems to cause the issue:

```
@Test
public void emailAlreadyExistsTest(){
    assertTrue(credentialRepo.emailIsAssigned("existing_email@yahoo.ca"));
}
```

And this is the error message that I have:

```
  [EL Warning]: 2017-04-17 17:55:33.606--ServerSession(234430897)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-3e4_9a'
Error Code: 1022
Call: ALTER TABLE credential ADD CONSTRAINT FK_credential_email FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES email (email_address)
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER TABLE credential ADD CONSTRAINT FK_credential_email FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES email (email_address)")
```

I would appreciate if someone could give me a piece of advice. I could always just change the email into a String and mark it as "unique" in `@Column`, but I feel that there is no reason for the chosen approach not to work.

I am using MySQL as the DB vendor, and Eclipse-Link JPA implementation. I did try to "hard-change" the name of the FK constraint but to no avail. The DB and all tables have the same collation (utf8_unicode_ci).

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the primary key for class Email because "extends MetaInfo"

Comment: I am afraid this is impossible. Deleting the `@Id` annotation will turn the .java file uncompilable. Besides MetaInfo is just an abstract class (`@MappedSuperclass`) - it doesn't have a primary key on its own.